# Bind return error 88

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to just bind a socket with this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int fd,namelen,newfd;
    struct sockaddr_in sin = {AF_INET};

    if(fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)==-1)
      printf("socket : %d\n",errno);

    if(bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin))==-1)
      printf("bind : %d\n",errno);
}
```

And that return "bind : 88", I think this mean ENOTSOCK fd, isn't a socket really ? or 88 isn't ENOTSOCK ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take care about parenthesis, in fact fd = 0 in your case.
Because `==` is evaluated before `=` (see [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)), your code is equivalent to `fd = (socket(...) == -1)`.

You should replace

```
if(fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)==-1)
```

with

```
if((fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))==-1)
```