# connect to socket failed - errno 88 (cpp)

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to create server/client communication and it faileson the connect function with errno 88. I checked if the socketfd is valid (because this errno means that I'm trying to make socket operation on non socket object).

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Validity check
if (argc != VALID_ARG_NUM) {
    std::cout << INVALID_ARG;
    return 0; // todo - return 0 is correct??
}

int port;
struct sockaddr_in server_address;

// server_address initialization.
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons((uint32_t)atof(argv[3]));
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
memset(&(server_address.sin_zero), '\0', sizeof(server_address));

// Create the client socket.
if (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: socket " << errno << "." << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
// Connect to server.
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: connect " << errno << "." << std::endl;
    std::cout << CON_FAIL;
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
}
.......
```

thank you.

Comment: If you have Boost available, or are able to download it, I would highly recommend using Boost Asio for socket programming.

Comment: The error codes in `errno` are really platform dependent. Please tell us which platform (operating system) you use. And use e.g. `strerror` to get a printable string from the error code.

Comment: sorry, the os is linux.

Comment: ok, I changed it like you told me, and it still stuck - with broken pipe..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind return error 88](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124746/bind-return-error-88)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precedence of the statement

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0
```

is

```
sockfd = ((socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
```

and you are therefore assigning a boolean, which is implicitly converted to an integer (or whatever type `sockfd` has). What you probably meant was instead

```
(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0
```

Comment: ok, I changed it like you told me, and it still stuck - with broken pipe..

Comment: @MichalShalom: Well, that is [an entirely different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4584904/147845).

Answer (score 1):

I think this part is causing buffer overrun:

```
memset(&(server_address.sin_zero), '\0', sizeof(server_address));
```

You should zero the whole struct before writing somefields:

```
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
// server_address initialization.
memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

Comment: I changed it, and still errno 88 :/

Answer (score 0):

Broken pipe usually means that remote peer closes connection. Are you sure your server code is OK? Maybe it just do something like this?

```
int main()
{
...
listen();
accept();

return 0;//procees exits and therefore brakes connection
}
```